# Angular 6 rendering images from server

Tags: angular6

I have an api call that returns a list of urls for the images I want to render (http://localhost/api/files/getimage/4/Tulips.jpg)

The images get rendered with localhost, but with a api server I get

"Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response with MIME type text/html. See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5629709824032768 for more details."

How to make it work?

```html
    <div *ngFor="let file of fileList">
        <img src={{file}} alt={{file}} />
    </div>
```

Comment: So, I had a typo and I have fixed it and it turned out that the CORB was a misleading warning. Now, image does not get downloaded at all with the remote server, no error message or warning. Any ideas?

Comment: It was a permissions issue, I had to give write access to the folder I was reading the images from

Answer (score 0):

```
 <div *ngFor="let file of fileList">
        <img src="{{file}}" alt="{{file}}" />
    </div>


 <div *ngFor="let file of fileList">
        <img [src]="file" alt="file" />
    </div>
```